# How can I call block and their action in static block?

Tags: magento

I can call my block in a **static block** as like this :

```
{{block type="facebooklikebox/likebox" template="facebooklikebox/likebox.phtml"}}
```

but how can I use this action in a static block :

```
  <action method="setData"><name>position</name><value>right</value></action>
  <action method="setData"><name>page_id</name><value>facebooklikebox/general/page_id</value></action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
{{block type="facebooklikebox/likebox" position="right" page_id="facebooklikebox/general/page_id" template="facebooklikebox/likebox.phtml"}}
```

Then retreive it inside with `getPosition` or `getPageId`.